# How a pointer can reference to a segment in hard disk

Tags: c++, c, linux, pointers, operating-system

please let me know how a pointer ( in C / C++ programming language ) can reference to a segment in hard disk, a storage of say upto 1 GB.

In more details i am going to write the signature of a function which will take a pointer as argument and that should point to a segment in hard disk, which can hold upto 1 GB space, instead of passing the pointer pointing to the address, which holds the same amount of storage, on heap I want it to point to hard disk segment. system is Linux, programming languages both C & C++.

Comment: i need that because i can only pass pointers and that pointer should point to a location which can hold a good amount of space in order to hold some binary images for future installation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look into [`mmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap). This allows to map files into your main memory.

Comment: Thanks Olaf, but the requirement is like the function signature that i will use is to be used by some external application and my application will only invoke the function and implementation will be responsibility of external application. so how can i use mmap() in this case, because i will only provide an interface, preferably a function, which will ensure that the external application on receiving the pointer will fetch the binary image which will be used later.

Comment: @Indranil You cannot pass pointers between pointers between programs, because every program has its own virtual memory. What comes closest, *if* I understand you correctly, would be sysv shared memory or mmap with MAP_SHARED.

Answer (score 4):

You have to map the data into your virtual address space.

open your file or block device (e.g. `/dev/sda`) with `open(2)` and pass the file descriptor here:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

void * map_file_descriptr(int fd) {
    struct stat file_stat;
    if (fstat(fd, &file_stat)) {
        perror("fstat");
        // do something on error
        return NULL;
    }

    void * data = mmap(
          NULL // place the the VM segment anywhere in the process virtual address space
        , file_stat.st_size // file size
        // For read-only:
        , PROT_READ
        , MAP_PRIVATE
        // for read-write
        /*
        , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE
        , MAP_SHARED
        */
        , fd // file which belongs to this file descriptor
        , 0 // from the beginning
        );

    if (data == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        // you most likely are out of memory to allocate the VM table
        // this very rarely happens
        return NULL;
    }

    return data;
}
```

If you mapped the file with `MAP_SHARED` for read-write access then you need to `msync(2)` it to flush the updates to disk.

Careful: Mapping a file with `MAP_PRIVATE` has undefined behaviour if the file is modified by another process after the mapping. Also any mapping will result in undefined behaviour if the file size is changed after the mapping.

Note: `MAP_PRIVATE` mappings with `PROT_WRITE` can be written to, but the changes will not be written back to the file when the mapping is removed, those mappings cannot be synched either.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sergey, I hope this is going to help me to get some work around, after mapping there is no possibility for the file size to get changed. Your insightful view and  map_file_descriptr() function has given me some clue which will be helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: Nother thing to note is that `mmap` does not actually allocate physical memory to your process. It only creates a usable virtual mapping. Once you start using it the file contents will be transparently copied into RAM one page at a time. Swapping on a `MAP_SHARED` mapping will write your changes back to the file instead of using swap space similar to what `msync` would do. Swapping on `MAP_PRIVATE` will go to swap space (if the mapping has been modified) since you have a private copy of the file.